# Ошибка работы функции scanf в си

Tags: c, visual-studio

Здравствуйте. При попытке компиляции проекта возникает следующая ошибка:

> Ошибка    C4996   'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. 
>   код программы:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: при использовании `scanf_s` компиляция проходит успешно, почему не работает с `scanf`? Среда разработки visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто функция считается небезопасной, позволяющей в принципе привести к переполнению буфера (и сопутствующим неприятностям, вплоть до взлома программы хакерами :))

Поэтому вас предупреждают об использовании *потенциально* небезопасной функции.

Используя

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

вы говорите - да, я знаю и принимаю на себя всю ответственность.

Comment: Ок, я использую  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS но почему даже при этом использовании возникает ошибка компиляции?

Comment: @Вячеслав161: Это значит, что вы НЕ используете `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. А уж что именно вы там напортачили - отсюда не видно.

Comment: Готово, проблема решена, нужно было лишь отключить использование предварительно скомпилированных заголовков))

Comment: нет, надо было просто переместить этот дефайн в stdafx.h, перед любыми включениями

Comment: @Вячеслав161 Только собрался написать, опередили :) Или - можно этот define внести в stdafx.h - тоже должно сработать.

Comment: Не совсем понял как реализовать этот перенос define в stdafx.h... Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Да просто открыть его в редакторе и внести.

Answer (score 2):

Это диагностическое сообщение является "ошибкой" только если у вас в установках проекта включены `SDL Checks`. Если выключить `SDL Checks`, то "ошибка" превратится в "предупреждение".

Чтобы избавиться от него полностью, определите макро `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` перед включением стандартных заголовочных файлов. Лучше всего сделать это глобально, в настройках проекта.